# Bug: clicking 'close' multiple times

Tags: bug, status-declined

Hello I wanted to vote for close, and it showed loading gif.. While it took too long to load I've clicked 'close' again and loading gifs duplicated, see image:

[image]

Comment: I have seen bug reports about this before. It happens when the Ajax calls don't finish or take a long time to complete.

Comment: but it should be simple to resolve, right? anyway it does not harm anything but...

Comment: Many, many open bugs are simple to resolve... just give it 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: The general consensus within the team is: **don't do that**.